# I am not able to boot with the latest kernel source ie 3.18.0 with the device tree enabled

Tags: linux, kernel, device-tree

I am  not able to boot with the latest kernel source ie 3.18.0 with the device tree enabled.
I am getting blank screen.

I used the [b]latest tools and firmware[/b] to boot.
downloaded the code from  https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.18.y and compiled it.

I followed the following steps to compile it.

```
ARCH=arm make bcmrpi_defconfig
CCPREFIX=rpi-tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CCPREFIX make -j4
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CCPREFIX INSTALL_MOD_PATH=modules make -j2 modules_install
```

/boot/config.txt content:

```
device_tree=bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
device_tree_address=0x100
kernel_address=0x8000
disable_commandline_tags=2
```

Plese let me know if anything i am missing.
Please Suggest me something.